# Google places tutorial NPE android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to do a google places tutorial i found on the net.But i am getting NPE in a certain class:

ShowGoogleMap.java

```
package com.gmap;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;


public class ShowGoogleMap extends MapActivity {

    protected static int updated_lat;
    protected static int updated_lng;

    // Used to add overlay markers of both type
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays;


    private boolean isPotentialLongPress;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    // adding your own place info
    static double addLat = 0;
    static double addLng = 0;
    static String locType = "cafe";
    static String LocName = "OffCourse Golf Hole";

    static String detailText;


    Button reloadButton;
    Button placeDetailsButton;
    Button addPlaceButton;


    private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.showmap);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        //mapView.setSatellite(true);

        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(14); // Zoom 1 is world view
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

        reloadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.relaod);
        placeDetailsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.place_details);
        addPlaceButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_place);

        // set place Button listener here
        reloadButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    SearchSrv srv = new SearchSrv();                
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                    srv.execute();  
            }   
        });

        // set Detail Button listener here
        placeDetailsButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (MyItemizedOverlay.reference == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please select your place marker first!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  
                }else{
                    DetailSrv srv = new DetailSrv();                
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                    srv.execute();
                }


            }   
        });

        // To show an AlertDialog Box
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Please select your location by long pressing")
               .setCancelable(false) 
               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });       


        // set add place Button listener here
        addPlaceButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                if (addLat == 0 && addLng == 0){
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();           
                }
                else{
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PlaceAdd.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);         
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                }
            }   
        });


    } // end onCreate() method here

        private class SearchSrv extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, PlacesList>{
            @Override
            protected PlacesList doInBackground(Void... params) {
                PlacesList pl = null;
                try {
                    // send place search request from here
                     pl = new PlaceRequest().performSearch();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return pl;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(PlacesList result) {

                Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.places_marker);
                int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
                int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
                marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);

                for(int i = 0; i < listOfOverlays.size(); i++){
                    if (i != 0){
                        listOfOverlays.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                // Here place searched are displayed on google map as Red markers
                if (result != null) {
                    int []lat = new int[PlaceRequest.latList.size()];
                    int []lng = new int[PlaceRequest.lngList.size()];

                    MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, ShowGoogleMap.this);
                    listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                    listOfOverlays.add(myItemizedOverlay);

                    for(int i = 0; i< PlaceRequest.latList.size(); i++) {                   
                        lat[i] = (int)(PlaceRequest.latList.get(i) * 1E6);
                        lng[i] = (int)(PlaceRequest.lngList.get(i) * 1E6);
                        Log.v("GPS", "My Place Location is: "+ lat[i] + "," + lng[i]);           

                        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat[i], lng[i]);
                        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(point, "OffCourse Golf Hole "+i, PlaceRequest.placeReference.get(i).toString());
                    } 
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            }
        }   // End of class SearchSrv here


        private class DetailSrv extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, PlaceDetail>{
            @Override
            protected PlaceDetail doInBackground(Void... params) {
                PlaceDetail pl = null;
                try {
                    // send place search request from here
                     pl = new PlaceRequest().performDetails(MyItemizedOverlay.reference);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return pl;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(PlaceDetail details) {
                Log.v(PlaceRequest.LOG_KEY, "Place details JSON format: " + details);
                //to display place Details
                detailText = "Place Details\n\n";

                if (details != null) {
                   Place place = details.result;  
                   detailText =  detailText + "id = " + place.id +"\n";
                   detailText =  detailText + "name = " +  place.name +"\n";
                   detailText =  detailText + "reference = " + place.reference +"\n";
                   detailText =  detailText + "types = " + place.types[0]+"\n";
                   detailText =  detailText + "phone_number = " + place.international_phone_number+"\n";
                   detailText =  detailText + "url = " + place.url +"\n";              
                   detailText =  detailText + "vicinity = " + place.vicinity +"\n";
                   detailText =  detailText + "website = " + place.website +"\n";
                   detailText =  detailText + "rating = " + place.rating +"\n";
                   detailText =  detailText + "formatted_address = " + place.formatted_address +"\n";
                   detailText =  detailText + "lat = " + place.geometry.location.lat +"\n";
                   detailText =  detailText + "lng = " + place.geometry.location.lng +"\n";

                   Log.v(PlaceRequest.LOG_KEY, "Details = " + detailText );          
               } 

                // To show my My Custom Dialog box: DetailDialog
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ShowPlaceDetail.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);         
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            }
        }   // End of class SearchSrv here


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        handleLongPress(event);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    // Here detecting user long press to add my own place
    private void handleLongPress( final MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // A new touch has been detected
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    if (isLongPressDetected()) {
                        // We have a long press! Perform your action here
                        GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());   
                        addLat = p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
                        addLng = p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
                        Log.v("Long Press", "Location on Touch: " + p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6+ "," +p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);                    
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (event.getHistorySize() < 1)
                return; // First call, no history

            // Get difference in position since previous move event
            float diffX = event.getX() - event.getHistoricalX(event.getHistorySize() - 1);
            float diffY = event.getY() - event.getHistoricalY(event.getHistorySize() - 1);

            /* If position has moved substatially, this is not a long press but probably a drag action */
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > 0.5f || Math.abs(diffY) > 0.5f) {
                isPotentialLongPress = false;
            }
        } else {
            // This motion is something else, and thus not part of a longpress
            isPotentialLongPress = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isLongPressDetected() {
        isPotentialLongPress = true;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(10);
                if (!isPotentialLongPress) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            isPotentialLongPress = false;
        }
    }


    public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {
        // To get user current location (latitude, longitude)
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updated_lat =  (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
            updated_lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
            Log.v("GPS", "Updated Lat , Updated Lng: "+ updated_lat + "," + updated_lng);
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(updated_lat, updated_lng);

            mapController.animateTo(point); //  mapController.setCenter(point);

            listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            if (listOfOverlays.isEmpty()){
                listOfOverlays.add(new MapOverlay(point));
            }
            else{
                // replace it
                 listOfOverlays.set(0, new MapOverlay(point));
            }         
            mapView.invalidate();
        }

    // Overlay for for user current location
    class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
         GeoPoint point = null;
         MapOverlay (GeoPoint point){
            this.point = point;
         }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, screenPts);

            //---add the marker---
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.user_marker);            
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-33, null); // 33 is height of marker     
            return true;
        }
    }  
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

}
```

LOGCAT:

```
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at com.gmap.ShowGoogleMap$SearchSrv.onPostExecute(ShowGoogleMap.java:159)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at com.gmap.ShowGoogleMap$SearchSrv.onPostExecute(ShowGoogleMap.java:1)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-01 14:06:38.187: E/AndroidRuntime(14123):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help..I am new to the google maps and places api.So i dont fully understand the code from the tutorial.

Comment: Which line is ShowGoogleMap.java:159

Comment: line 159 is for(int i = 0; i < listOfOverlays.size(); i++){

Comment: There must be something is linje no 159 of showGoogleMap class that you have not initialised

Comment: The listofOverlays is showing NPE.can someone suggest as how to initialize that vairable to prevent NPE?

Comment: listOfOverlays is null. Have you initialized it before using?

Comment: Looks like you never get a locationUpdate so `listOfOverlays` is null

Comment: issue Solved or still error??

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to initialise your arraylist oh listOfOverlays before you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `listOfOverlays` like this:

```
List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = new ArrayList<Overlay>();
```

That will remove NPE.